# Why is the Compact Symplectic Group Simply Connected

Tags: lie-groups, compact-manifolds

Let $Sp(n)=U(n,\mathbb{H})=\{A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{H}) : A\cdot A^{*}=I\}$ be the compact symplectic group, a subset of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$. I want to show that $Sp(n)$ is simply connected, in accordance with [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group#Sp.28n.29).

I know that for the case $n=1$, we can write elements of $Sp(1)$ in the form $\cos\theta+v\sin\theta$, where $v$ is a purely imaginary unit quaternion; this gives us a nice, explicit path to the identity. I'm not sure what argument to make for higher dimensions, though. I don't have much experience in dealing with Lie groups or smooth manifolds, so I'm not familiar with any "standard" methods of proving simple connectedness in these objects.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Do you want connectedness or simply connectedness? Your argument for $n = 1$ only shows path connectedness.

Comment: The general approach to simply connectedness is to use induction on the chain of embeddings $Sp(n-1) \rightarrow Sp(n)$ and to figure out what manifold the homogenous spaces $Sp(n)/Sp(n-1)$ look like. For example, you can prove that $SL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is simply connected by noting that $SL_{1} = 1$ is a point and then noting that for $n \ge 2$, 
$$SL_{n}/SL_{n-1}$$
looks like $\mathbb{C}^{n} \backslash\{0\}$. Since $SL_{n-1}$ is assumed simply connected by induction and $\mathbb{C}^{n} \backslash\{0\}$ is simply connected, the long exact sequence of homotopy tells us that so is $SL_{n}$.